# has a bug in this program to find the factorial of numbers 1 to 20 in java

Tags: java

this code is working fine for numbers 1 to 12 but after that its showing the wrong result can somebody explain ?

```
package logicProgramming;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner KB=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=KB.nextInt();
    while (t-->0)
    {
        int b=KB.nextInt();
        if(b>0 && b<21)
        {
            int f=b;
            for(int i=1;i<b;i++){
                f=f*i;
             }
             System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Often big numbers become negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218964/often-big-numbers-become-negative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use something longer than type int, 12 factorial is 479,001,600, the maximum integer value in Java is 2,147,483,647. 13 factorial gives 6,227,020,800, this is bigger than the type int can hold

Answer (score 1):

You have defined f (the result variable) as an int. The range for the int type in java is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (32 bits, signed). If you want to store larger values, consider using primitive `long`, or class [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).