# Why command line argument -12345678969 is considered to be >1?

Tags: c, command-line, int, argv, atoi

This is the program to check whether given number is Armstrong number or not

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int num,n,sum=0;
    num=atoi(argv[1]);
    if(argc==2 && num>0 && num<=INT_MAX)    
    {   n=num;
        while(num>0)
        {
            sum+=(num%10)*(num%10)*(num%10);
            num/=10;
        }
        if(sum==n)
            printf("%d is an armstrong number",n);
        else    
            printf("%d is not an armstrong number",n);
        return 0;    
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

**Here i gave an input**

-12345678969

**expected output**

Command exited with non-zero status 1

but it shows

539222919 is not an armstrong number

Comment: See `INT_MIN` in `limits.h` `int` can't store any value that won't fit in... well, whatever size an `int` is on your platform, and this number is outside that range. If you used `long`s instead of `int`s, you wouldn't have this particular problem.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: ...for example, on MacOS X, `/usr/include/i386/limits.h` defines `INT_MIN` as `(-2147483647-1)`; notably, `-12345678969` is smaller than that, so it can't be stored in an `int`.

Comment: BTW, `int` is generally 32 bits. You might want [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (or at least [`int64_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)...). Consider [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: `num <= INT_MAX` is meaningless if `num` is an `int`. It **can't possibly** be assigned a value outside the realm of what an `int` can store, because, well, *it's an `int`*.

Comment: See also [Why shouldn't I use `atoi`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi); compare to `strtol`, which has well-defined underflow and overflow behaviors, and provides a means to detect errors (which, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24599796/14122) demonstrates).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Often big numbers become negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218964/often-big-numbers-become-negative)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi)

Answer (score 4):

The number '-12345678969' requires too many bits for an int. An int in most C compilers is [32-bits wide](https://usrmisc.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/integer-sizes-in-c-on-32-bit-and-64-bit-linux/), however that is not enough bits to be able to contain '-12345678969'.

`atoi()` simply tries to convert the number to a 32-bit integer, meaning a part of the input value of '-12345678969' is cut off; In base 2 (binary) representation the input number would fit in a 64-bit integer as:

`1111111111111111111111111111110100100000001000111110001110000111`

And when `atoi()` cuts off the high order 32 bits, the low order 32 bits remain:

`00100000001000111110001110000111`

which contains no sign any more (the bit you read first from the left is 0, meaning there is no sign and thus the number is not negative in a signed `int`).

That number in decimal representation would be equal to `539222919`, which is the number you see in your case.

Comment: More on that concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

And interesting historical reference to integer overflow: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/ariane.html

Answer (score 2):

```
-12345678969
```

in hex is

```
0xFFFFFFFD2023E387
```

<sup>(each digit represents 4 bits)</sup>

`atoi()` returns an `int`, which mostly likely is 32 bits.

Taking the least significant 32 bits of `0xFFFFFFFD2023E387` gives us `0x2023E387` which in fact is

```
539222919
```

in decimal.

Comment: Yo won't believe what happened now. I just was using `-123456789` and not getting same as you. Should be more awake. Yes I was aware of that..just trying to find where I was going wrong

Comment: @coderredoc: Just memorise that 4 000 000 000 and bit soon breaks the (unsigned) 32bit barrier .... :-)

Comment: .: `4000 000 000` what do you mean?

Comment: @coderredoc: I mean the number 4000000000 is nearly equal to the maximum you can store using 32 bits. If you memorised this you would not have assumed 123456789 (which obviously is much smaller then 4000000000) to be a relevant value in this context, you would not have made the mistake you mentioned. ;-)

Comment: .: I see...the decimal 4000..00 - I will remmeebr it. Yep.  If it was -123456789 then also it would fit in.