# Fibonacci sequence has a negative number

Tags: java, class, arraylist, fibonacci

I have this code for fibonacci sequence :

```
public class Fibonacci {
    private List<Integer> fibonacci;

    public void fillFibonacci(){
        fibonacci = new ArrayList<>();
        int n1 = 1 , n2 = 1 , n3;
        fibonacci.add(n1);
        fibonacci.add(n2);
        for(int i = 2 ; i < 4000 ; i ++){
            n3 = n1 + n2;
            fibonacci.add(n3);
            n1=n2;
            n2=n3;
        }
    }

    public void printFibonacci(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < fibonacci.size() ; i ++){
            System.out.print(fibonacci.get(i) + " ");
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

this code show negative number what's wrong with it?

Comment: Ints have a limited range. When they get too high, they overflow.

Comment: See [Often big numbers become negative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17218964/3890632)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot go up to index= 4000 in this loop, you have *integer overflowed*. Maximum you can go to is 49. Change the loop as such.

```
for(int i = 2 ; i < 49 ; i ++){
            n3 = n1 + n2;
            fibonacci.add(n3);
            n1=n2;
            n2=n3;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 4000-th Fibonacci number has 836 digits. The java int type has 32-bits and can fit numbers up to 10 digits. After that it overflows and may go negative. If you want big numbers, change your code to use `BigInteger`.